# why does the do while loop doesn't break?

Tags: c++, loops, data-structures, switch-statement, do-while

I am having problem with following code

```
switch(adminChoice){
    case 1:
        do{
            cout<<"\nEnter Student ID: ";
            cin>>studentId;
            cout<<"\nEnter Student Name: ";
            cin>>studentName;
            cout<<"\nEnter Student Password: ";
            cin>>studentPassword;
            cout<<"\nAdd another account? y/n ";
            cin>>adminSubChoice;
        }
        while(adminSubChoice!='n' || adminSubChoice !='N');
        break;
    case 2:
```

the `do while` doesn't break when I enter n or N for the `char` variable `adminSubChoice` it keeps on running again and again. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Thanks dude. I got my answer and also it is mentioned in the question adminSubChoice is char type variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `adminSubChoice!='n' || adminSubChoice !='N'` will be always true because no character will be both `n` and `N` at the same time.

The condition should be `adminSubChoice!='n' && adminSubChoice !='N'`.

Comment: As a follow-up to this answer, consider reading up on De Morgan's laws, as they appear to be what you were trying to figure out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws.

Comment: @MikeCAT it worked. I got it now. Thank you

Comment: @Welbog yup I got confused in OR & AND operator. Thank you I will check it out